# How to move JQuery DatePickers ahead of other form elements

Tags: css, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am new to CSS and JQuery. I have a C# MVC application that has several forms and I want to use the JQuery datepicker control. What I am seeing is that the datepicker is there, but it is hard to see and is obscured by the other boxes in the form.

All I can do is really describe it, since the site will not allow me to upload images in this question (I keep getting a "Service Unavailable" error). When I click on the editor in the view, I can see the datepicker calendar appear, but it is basically getting all mashed up with the other form boxes below it (to the point where it obscures parts of the calendar).

My markup code is here:

```
@section Scripts
{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/cssjqryUi")

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('input[type=datetime]').datepicker({
         dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",
         changeMonth: true,
         changeYear: true,
         yearRange: "-60:+5",            
     });
 });
</script>
}

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.LabelFor(model =>
                        model.ExpiryDate,
                        "Expiry Date",
                        htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ExpiryDate, new { @class = "datepicker"})
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.LabelFor(model =>
                        model.IssuanceFeeValue,
                        "Issuance Fee Value",
                        htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.IssuanceFeeValue)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.IssuanceFeeValue, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.LabelFor(model =>
                        model.Tenor,
                        "Tenor",
                        htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTenor, Model.TenorList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedTenor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.LabelFor(model =>
                        model.Tranche,
                        "Tranche",
                        htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTranche,Model.TrancheList)
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried tinkering with the z-index and that did nothing. Note sure what I am missing here.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

---

UPDATE

I have a picture that I can upload of what the markup looks like:

[image]

Comment: try to upload an image to an external image upload service and supply the link here. we can't help if we can't see the problem

Comment: Got a picture of the markup.

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle. It makes easier to understand your problem and solve it faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same exact issue a few days ago, this problem is because you are probably  missing a jquery-ui.css file.

try adding this file to your page:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css